# Transform Json object to an array of key value pairs in NiFi

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I have a json object in this form

```
{
    "email" : "test@gmail.com",
    "name" : "somename",
    "age" : "someage"
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I want to to translate the above json to

```
[{
  "key" : "email",
  "value": "test@gmail.com"
},
{
  "key" : "name",
  "value": "somename"
},
{
  "key" : "age",
  "value": "someage"
}]
```

I want to do the above transformation using available NiFi processors. Also, in my requirement, json object fields are dynamic and I need to build a solution to transform the object as an array of objects with key and value fields. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the `JoltTransformJSON` processor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `Spec` in `JoltTransformJSON`:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "[#2].Key",
        "@": "[#2].Value"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Screenshot**
[image]